# Opencv findCountours function

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to learn opencv. Online i found that, with opencv, I can obtain the contours of some image. So i tried that. Here is the script:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def getC(imagine):
    global imgContour
    c,h = cv2.findContours(imagine,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    for cnt in c:
        a = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        print(area)
        if area>500:
            cv2.drawContour(imgContour,cnt,-1,(255,0,0),3)

img = cv2.imread("a3.jpg")
imgContour = img.copy()
imgG = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
imgB = cv2.GaussianBlur(imgG,(7,7),1)
imgC = cv2.Canny(imgB,50,50)

getC(imgContour)

cv2.imshow("",img)
cv2.imshow("g",imgG)
cv2.imshow("b",imgB)
cv2.imshow("l",imgContour)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I think there is a problem with global variabiles, but also with the format. a3.jpg is that [image](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nonnainfabula.com%2Fwordpress%2Fprogetto-educativo-le-forme-rivolto-ai-genitori%2F&psig=AOvVaw1Qj_H2KDHHKR-4KDw5x-rt&ust=1593335887870000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCLi8jfHUoeoCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD).

I don't now what to do now, and how to resolve the issue.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you saved the area as the variable `a` but used it with the name `area` you can fix this by changing the variable name `a` to `area`

```py
area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
```

2. there is a typo in `cv2.drawContour` you should write it like that `cv2.drawContours`
3. `cv2.drawContours` method expects the contour you want to draw to be a list of lists so you need to call it like that

```py
cv2.drawContours(imgContour,[cnt],-1,(255,0,0),3)
```

4. when you pass the image to the `getC` method you gave it an image without pre-processing this image and converting it to threshold image using canny so you need to call it like that

```py
getC(imgC)
```

### The Final Script

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def getC(imagine):

    global imgContour
    print(imgContour.shape)
    c,h = cv2.findContours(imagine,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    for cnt in c:
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        print(area)
        if area>500:
            cv2.drawContours(imgContour,[cnt],-1,(255,0,0),3)


img = cv2.imread("./a3.jpg")
imgContour = img.copy()

imgG = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
imgB = cv2.GaussianBlur(imgG,(7,7),1)
imgC = cv2.Canny(imgB,50,50)

getC(imgC)

cv2.imshow("",img)
cv2.imshow("g",imgG)
cv2.imshow("b",imgB)
cv2.imshow("l",imgContour)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```